# Popup background doesn't hide when closing

Tags: javascript, css, html, popup

I created a popup and then moved it over to the final domain. Now the background overlay (`#overlay-back`) doesn't hide when closing via the 'X' (`.close-image`) in the corner, yet it does when pressing ESC. Something I've missed?

Here's the live site: http://www.nominee-services.co.uk/

**JS :**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#overlay-back').fadeIn(800, function () {
            $('#popup').show();
        });

        $(".close-image").on('click', function () {
            $('#popup').hide()
        });
    });
    $(".close-image").on('click', function () {
        $('#overlay-back').hide();
    });
    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
            $('#popup').hide();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
            $('#overlay-back').hide();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('#popup').length === 0) {
            $('#overlay-back').hide();
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('#popup').length === 0) {
            $('#popup').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**CSS :**

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 960px;
    height: 98px;
    margin-top: -194px;
    margin-left: -480px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 20;
    padding: 5px;
}
#overlay-back {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index: 19;
    display: none;
}
.close-image {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 21;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="popup">
    <img class="close-image" src="images/closebtn.png" /><span><img src="images/load_sign.png" width="960" height="398" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try both in one click, hiding popup and hiding the overlay, why you are doing it separately?

Comment: Have you run it through a [js lint tool](http://www.jshint.com/) ?

Comment: `overlay-back`  in this class give `z-index:1; position:relative;`

Comment: @iBlue Fiddle created: http://jsfiddle.net/EBv9v/2/ here it's working fine! :(

Comment: @Fags tried this, it hides the `overlay-back` completely

@DKM I have no idea how I'd go about doing that :/ it did cross my mind though

Comment: @BradAdams It seems you have closed the `document.ready()` function before the `$('#overlay-back').hide();` click event.

Comment: @BradAdams No worries, I'd suggest following formatting standards (indentation's etc..) which makes errors like this easy to spot.

Comment: @YaMo yeah, now it's as if I see how it works (after going through and sorting formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the click event in `document.ready()` function.

```
$(".close-image").on('click', function() {
       $('#overlay-back').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you set your events twice ?

```
     $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        if ( $( e.target ).closest('#popup').length === 0 ) {
        $('#overlay-back').hide();
}
});
     $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
       if ( $( e.target ).closest('#popup').length === 0 ) {
       $('#popup').hide();
}
});
```

Just change it to

```
       $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
       if ( $( e.target ).closest('#popup').length === 0 ) {
       $('#popup').hide();
       $('#overlay-back').hide();
}
});
```

Also if you have a event (for examle window.load ) and you set it twice, you overwrite the previous associated function. Not sure if it works that way for all events but it yould be your problem.

Comment: I'm quite new to Jquery, etc therefore had no idea how to do this. After seeing your example I've applied this to all of the code and it's now working fine. As @Dinesh mentioned I had closed the document.ready() function too early (and when removing extra functions I ended up moving them to the correct place). Thanks! :)